A curve with corners is not a submanifold
Consider the graph of the absolute value function as a curve on the plane. It is intuitively clear that the origin is a "singular" point, and that this prevents this curve from being an immersed submanifold of the plane.
How can this fact be properly stated and proved?
(in the general case, and not just for the absolute value graph).
For example, in the study of algebraic curves one can define a singularity by looking at the intersection multiplicity of the curve with lines.
In differential geometry we know that, if a subset $C$ of $\mathbb R^n$ is given as the zero locus of a function $F$ and a point $p$ on $C$ is regular (i.e. the differential of $F$ at $p$ is surjective), then $p$ has a neighbourhood whose intersection with $C$ is a smooth embedded submanifold. However, if the point is critical, we can't conclude that there is a "true" singularity. For example the function $F(x,y)=x^2$ defines a perfectly well embedded submanifold, but every point is critical for the function $F$. Hence, how can we give a meaningful definition (maybe restricted to some specific class of cases) of what I called a singularity?
It seems to me that (restrincting for simplicity to the case of curves) in order to give a definition of singular point on a curve we should first define what a curve is. The straightforward definition as a 1-dimensional submanifold doesn't work, because in this case there would not be any singular point. Hence a more useful possibility could be through a parametrization. However, if we then use a parametrization to define, e.g., the notion of a singular point, then we have to show that it is independent on the chosen parametrization.
Following this route I've arrived to the following conjecture, which is about a specific case (curve with corners). I would like to know whether it is true and, apart from proving or disproving it, how to deal with this general problem.
Consider a piecewise regular curve in $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. a continuous function $r\colon (a,b)\to \mathbb R^n$ and a subdivision $a=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_m=b$ such that the restriction of $r$ to $[t_i,t_{i+1}]$ is a smooth function with nonvanishing derivative. Assume moreover that right and left limits of the derivative are finite at the points $t_i$ and that $r$ is a homeomorphism onto its image. We say that there is a corner at the point $p=r(t_i)$ if the limits $$c_i^+:=\lim_{t\to t_i ^+} r'(t)$$ and $$c_i^-:=\lim_{t\to t_i ^-} r'(t)$$ are such that $c_i^+\neq\lambda c_i^-$ for any $\lambda>0$.
Conjecture: If the curve $r$ has a corner, then its image is not an immersed sumbanifold of $\mathbb R^n$.
In order to show this, it should be sufficient to prove that, if $p=r(t_i)$ is a corner, there isn't any smooth function $\phi\colon (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to \mathbb R^n$ taking values in the image of $r$ and such that

$\phi'(t)\neq 0$ for all $t\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$
$\phi(0)=p$ is the corner.

This last statement encodes in some sense the parametrization invariance of the "corner", meaning that any other parametrization must have the corner and cannot hence be smooth.
However I can't find an easy way to prove it. I'd appreciate if someone could help me.

Your $r$ is a function, of course it cannot be a submanifold (since functions and submanifolds are different things). Are you asking if the image of $r$ cannot be the image of some immersion?

Yes, of course. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll correct it.

OK, now construct a counter example to your conjecture using the circle as the image of your map $r$ (which, of course, will not be injective).

More interestingly, even if you assume that $r$ is injective, there are counter examples.

I made some edits in order to make clearer what I'm aiming to. Probably the conjecture doesn't work (and I would be glad to see some "nontrivial" counterexample), but I would like then to know how to change it in order to make it work, if it is possible. The underlying idea is very simple and I'm interested in finding how and to which extent it can be formalized and proved.

Well, it is true, for instance, if you consider injective piecewise-smooth maps $r: S^1\to \mathbb  R^n$. Maybe this is what you are interested in.

In light of Moishe Kohan's counterexamples, I must correct my answer.
The following is a proof of the claim that

If the curve $r$ has a corner, then its image is not an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The definition of corner is that given by the OP except that it must hold for all $\lambda \neq 0$, not only $\lambda \gt 0$.

This is weaker than OP's original conjecture but is nonetheless interesting.

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be the image of $r$ and suppose $S$ is an embedded submanifold. Clearly $S$ must be one-dimensional since the restriction of $r$ to intervals $(t_i, t_{i+1})$ is a smooth immersion and $S$ is thus a union of finitely many one-dimensional topological manifolds and points, so if it is a manifold at all, it must be one-dimensional. Then the tangent space $T_pS$ must also be one-dimensional.
But if $r$ has a corner at $t_i$ then $c_i^+ = r'(t_i^+)$ and $c_i^- = r'(t_i^-)$ are both elements of $T_pS$ and they are linearly independent so $\dim T_pS \geq 2$ so $S$ cannot be an embedded submanifold.

Why are $r'(t_i^+)$ and $r'(t_i^-)$ elements of $T_pS$?
Let $\tilde{r}^+$ be a smooth extension of $r\vert_{[t_i, t_{i+1}]}$ and let $\tilde{r}^-$ be a smooth extension of $r\vert_{[t_{i-1}, t_i]}$, both defined on open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ containing their original domains.
We can define derivations $v^+, v^-$ such that for all smooth functions $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$v^+f = \lim\limits_{t\to t_i^+}\frac{f(r(t)) - f(p)}{t - t_i}$$
$$v^-f = \lim\limits_{t\to t_i^-}\frac{f(r(t)) - f(p)}{t - t_i}$$
We must first show that these limits exist. Let $\tilde{f}$ be a smooth extension of $f$ defined on a neighborhood of $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then we have
$$\lim\limits_{t\to t_i^+}\frac{f(r(t)) - f(p)}{t - t_i} =  \lim\limits_{t\to t_i^+}\frac{\tilde{f}(\tilde{r}^+(t)) - \tilde{f}(p)}{t - t_i} = (\tilde{f}\circ\tilde{r}^+)'(t_i)$$
$$\lim\limits_{t\to t_i^-}\frac{f(r(t)) - f(p)}{t - t_i} =  \lim\limits_{t\to t_i^-}\frac{\tilde{f}(\tilde{r}^-(t)) - \tilde{f}(p)}{t - t_i} = (\tilde{f}\circ\tilde{r}^-)'(t_i)$$
It is easy to see that $v^+$ and $v^-$ are linear in $f$. The product rule can also be checked from the definitions. So $v^+$ and $v^-$ are derivations at $p$.
Choosing functions $f = x^j$ for $j = 1, \ldots, n$ we get $v^{+,j} = {r^j}'(t_i^+)$ and $v^{-,j} = {r^j}'(t_i^-)$, so $v^+$ and $v^-$ have coordinate forms given by $r'(t_i^+)$ and $r'(t_i^-)$.

I do not know if this counter-example to your conjecture qualifies as "nontrivial," but here it is:
Take $n=1$, and consider the following function $r: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$:
$$
r(t)=\begin{cases}
t+2, & t\le -1\\
-t, & -1\le t\le 1\\
t-2, & t\ge 1
\end{cases}
$$
The image of this function is the entire $\mathbb R$, but it obviously has "corners" according to your definition.
As a more interesting example, consider the "figure 8 curve":

It is the image of an injective immersion of an open interval and is, in a sense, a standard counter-example to naive conjectures about immersed submanifolds. I will leave you as an exercise to find its "parameterization" as the image of an injective curve with one corner in your sense.

The first counterexample seems to be due to OP's definition of corners being $c_i^+ \neq \lambda c_i^-$ for $\lambda \gt 0$ instead of $\lambda \neq 0$. But the second counterexample is substantial and forced me to correct my answer to only deal with embedded submanifolds.

@TobErnack: OP might have had reasons for this definition, motivated by cuspidal singularities. But I do not know for sure.

@TobErnack A curve with cuspidal singularity is given by the equation $x^3=y^2$. It is a topological submanifold of the plane, not smooth, but admits a parameterization with one corner in OP's sense (but has no corners in your sense).
